# add cursor.fetchall data into list python sql

Tags: python, sql, list

This sql query on python 
`cursor.execute("SELECT name, COUNT(name) FROM class_1 GROUP BY name")` returns `(name, X)` when I call `print(cursor.fetchall())`, where `X` is an integer.

I want to put the `X` into a list, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
L=[]
itr=cursor.execute("SELECT name, COUNT(name) FROM class_1 GROUP BY name").fetchall()
for x in itr:
    L.append(x[2])
```